# Compiler option to globally changing symbol name?

Tags: ios, objective-c, c, clang

Asking this for a friend.

Suppose in my iOS project I am given a third-party static library (.a) to which I have no source code access and which is statically linked against an open source project. I'm using this open source project static library as well, but with a newer version. Since it's iOS they need to be all statically linked. To avoid duplicated symbol, during compilation is there an option I could give to the Clang compiler (or I'm personally also interested in GCC) to globally mangle of this newer version of open source library (maybe suppose I compile it to a static library first) that I am to link to?

In another word, to link to a ".a", is there a way to name mangle the symbols during compile time, such as prepending it with a prefix, such that no symbol conflicts can occur? If it cannot be done by compilers, is there a tool to name mangle it on a global scale?

Or, any other solution to avoiding duplicated symbols are appreciated, thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Two thoughts:

1) It's much easier to put a prefix on the library that you get to compile.  That's probably less satisfying, but it's an easy solution.

2) I found this Googling:

http://web.mit.edu/~jfc/src/sym-rename.c

It looks like it will append a prefix to everything in an ELF symbol table.  Presumably you'd explode your archive with ar, run that on it, and then recombine it again.

Comment: For 1), really? There could be a bunch of private functions, static vars, etc. And the next time a newer version come...ouch. 2) Interesting, amazing the code is so short, too. Unfortunately, iOS binary isn't in ELF.